# mysql query with GROUP BY not get all rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

awards:

```
awardsid,
forumid
```

forum:

```
forumid,
title
```

When I make a query to get all forums with count of awards for that forum, the query does not return all rows. If database Contain 4 rows it only returns 3. The result is always 1 less row than what is expected.

```
$forumdata = $db->query_read(" SELECT COUNT(awards.forumid) AS awardscount,forum.title,awards.forumid
FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . " awards AS awards
 INNER JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . " forum AS forum ON (forum.forumid = awards.forumid)
 GROUP BY awards.forumid ");
       if($db->fetch_array($forumdata))
       {

                while ($awards = $db->fetch_array($forumdata))
                {
                $title .= $awards['title'];
                $awardscount .= $awards['awardscount'];
                echo $title.':'.$awardscount.'<br />';
                }
       }
       else
       {
        echo "No Data";
       }
```

Comment: do `left join` instead of `inner join`

Comment: your `if` subtracts first row.

Comment: same problem , i try it already @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: ah @Notulysses is right you are doing fetch_array inside if you may need to use get_num_rows() instead.

Comment: you dun need if here seriously if u want to add echo NO data then u can write like if (empty($yourvariable)){ echo "no data";}

Comment: @ Notulysses ,Yeah , you are right thnx , i replace it `if($db->fetch_array($forumdata))` to  `if(mysql_num_rows($forumdata)>0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fetch your first row in the `if` clause , so in the while you are `echo`ing rows from 2 to n . I don't know how you are implementing your class to access mysql, so you can use something like this :

```
echo isset($title) ? '' : 'No data';
```

After your `while` loop and of course you should get rid of your `if/else` clauses in the way they are presented now.

Comment: thnx , i replace it `if($db->fetch_array($forumdata))` to `if(mysql_num_rows($forumdata)>0)` and worked well

Answer (score 0):

Change your:

```
 while ($awards = $db->fetch_array($forumdata))
                {
                $title .= $awards['title'];
                $awardscount .= $awards['awardscount'];
                echo $title.':'.$awardscount.'<br />';
                }
```

to

```
do
                {
                $title .= $awards['title'];
                $awardscount .= $awards['awardscount'];
                echo $title.':'.$awardscount.'<br />';
                }
while ($awards = $db->fetch_array($forumdata));
```

You are reading it twice in the beginning before processing

Comment: thnx , i replace it `if($db->fetch_array($forumdata))` to `if(mysql_num_rows($forumdata)>0)` and worked well

Comment: I guess going with your original way of if else and having the above do while change would give you a slight performance advantage though.

However, it would matter only if you are firing this query very frequently.